# Linear Algebra Problem on a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be an odd integer and  $A$  an $n \times n$  symmetric matrix with integer entries such that all diagonal entries are zero. Show that $detA$ is even.

#### My Attempt

Since all the entries of $A$ are integers its characteristic polynomial $p(x)\in Z[x]$ with the constant term of $p(x)$ being the determinant of $A$. If I can show that 2 is an eigenvalue of $A$ then we are done. But I can't exhibit such an eigenvector.

Please Help.

Comment: Certainly $2$ is not always an eigenvale; given any such matrix $A$, $\lambda A$ also satisfies the hypotheses for any integer, and in particular, we can choose $\lambda$ large enough such that all of its nonzero eigenvalues is $> 2$ in absolute value.

Comment: Maybe you could use eigenvalues, but it's probably easier to use the formula for the determinant
$$
\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}
$$
and note that every term added appears twice

Comment: Yes, 2 may not be eigenvalue. Can it be done without using the determinant formula?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the matrix $A$ mod 2. Then $A$ becomes a symmetric matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$. It suffices to show that the row vectors are linearly dependent. This can be done by devising an algorithm to choose some row vectors which sum to 0.